# Using VLookup with Conditional Formatting when Inserting a New Row

Tags: excel, vba, vlookup, conditional-formatting

I have two sheets and I am trying to re-apply the conditional formatting to Sheet 1 (Test 1) whenever a row is inserted into Row 2 of Sheet 1 (I have made my code apply the conditional formatting whenever Cell A2 is changed).

For the conditional formatting, I want to check if each visible cell in Column A Sheet 1 exists in Column A Sheet 2 with a Vlookup, and if it does then apply a Green conditional format to it.

I have two different codes I am trying to use in Sheet 1 ("Test 1") and both of them are applying the conditional format with the formulas, but none of the cells in Sheet 1 Column A are turning green when meeting the condition I have set with the formula.

Here are both of my codes, I only need one to work, just different formulas:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then

    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Range("A" & Sheet4.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With Range("A2:A" & lr)

            .FormatConditions.Delete

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Formula1:="IF(ISLBANK(Vlookup(A2,'Test 2'!$A:$B,1,False)),TRUE,FALSE)"

            .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

And the second Formula I have also tried is:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)

 If Target.Address = "$A$2" Then

    Dim lr As Long

    lr = Range("A" & Sheet4.rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

        With Range("A2:A" & lr)

            .FormatConditions.Delete

            .FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="Not(ISERROR(Vlookup(A2,'Test 2'!$A:$B,1,False)))"

            .FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen

        End With

    End If

End Sub
```

Cross-posted with: https://www.mrexcel.com/board/threads/using-vlookup-with-conditional-formatting-when-inserting-a-new-row.1126560/

**I will update both posts if I get an answer, thank you!**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second snippet is close, you are missing an `=` before the `Not`:

```
Formula1:="=Not(ISERROR(Vlookup(A2,'Test 2'!$A:$B,1,False)))"
```

Note the quotes around the entire formula in the screenshot below, which is what you currently have:
[image]

A simpler formula to use could be the following:

```
Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)>0"
```

**EDIT**: Based on comments, adding a second rule could look like this:

```
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)>0"
.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0"

.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen
.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)
```

Comment: Oh I see, thanks for catching that I didn't notice the missing `=`. And that Countif statement also seems to do the trick with a simpler code, thanks for that as well! Is there any way I can add something simple to make the mismatched cells in Sheet 1 red? Something to include your suggestion slightly modified, so the formula would be something along the lines of `Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0"`

Comment: Yes - that would be a separate rule.

Comment: After `.FormatConditions(1).Interior.Color = vbGreen` I tried to add `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula2:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0)"` & `.FormatConditions(2).Interior.Color = RGB(255, 199, 206)` but it seems to be giving me an error, first time using conditional formatting in VBA so I apologize if this is not how you're supposed to add a separate rule. Do I just have to make a completely new With statement and include this, or can I add it to the current with statement?

Comment: I seem to be getting "Run-time error '449': Argument Not Optional" as my error https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/Language/Reference/User-Interface-Help/argument-not-optional-error-449 on line `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula2:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0)" `

Comment: `Formula1`, not `Formula2`.

Comment: I see, I have `.FormatConditions.Add Type:=xlExpression, Operator:=xlExpression, Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0)"` & now it produces a run-time error 5, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/invalid-procedure-call-or-argument-error-5?f1url=https%3A%2F%2Fmsdn.microsoft.com%2Fquery%2Fdev11.query%3FappId%3DDev11IDEF1%26l%3Den-US%26k%3Dk(vblr6.chm1000005)%3Bk(TargetFrameworkMoniker-Office.Version%3Dv16)%26rd%3Dtrue

Comment: Remove the parenthesis after the `0`.

Comment: Funny - you had `Formula1:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0"` in your first [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60552989/using-vlookup-with-conditional-formatting-when-inserting-a-new-row/60553411#comment107127931_60553411) so idk how that got changed to `Formula2:="=COUNTIF('Test 2'!$A:$A,A2)=0)"`.